# .load() passing a POST request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django, templates

Here is an example loading a django template from an input box using ajax .load().

script for load method

```
$( document ).ready( function() {
    $( '#searchSubmit' ).click( function() {
        q = $( '#q' ).val();
        $( '#results' ).html( '&nbsp;' ).load( '{% url "demo_user_search" %}?q=' + q );
    });
});
```

from views.py

```
return render_to_response( template, data, context_instance = RequestContext( request ) )
```

vs. 
script for post method

```
 $.ajax({
        url : "/ajaxexample_json",
        type : "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data : data2,
        success : function(json) {
            show_results(json); 
        },
        error : function(xhr,errmsg,err) {
            alert(xhr.status + ": " + xhr.responseText);
        }
        });
        return false;
    });
```

and from the views.py

```
return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(response_dict), mimetype='application/javascript')
```

I don't know if there is a way for the POST method load a render_to_response template on success, so far I've tried and gotten a 200: error and a pop up (although all of the relevant txt/html is rendered in the pop up).

Is it possible to submit a POST with the .load() function instead?

Answer (score 1):

To use `POST` when using `$.load()`, you must pass a JSON object as the second parameter. The second parameter (when it is an object) is treated as data and sent to the backend via a POST request.

[Source](http://api.jquery.com/load/) (Look for 'Request Method')

Comment: You're right - I found an example here to: http://www.micahcarrick.com/ajax-form-submission-django.html, although it's a little dated.